# Is there any way to access a cached version of a webpage?

Tags: website, cache

My school publishes the homework on a website called Corebaby.org and we had some homework that we were supposed to do over the summer and I admit, I procrastinated until the weekend before school starts. I know, I know, I should have done my work earlier, but please... I am desperate here.

There were four assignments that we were supposed to to and I have gotten two and a half finished, but I need the website for the remaining parts. I tried using Google, Bing and Yahoo to try and view the cached page, but for some reason, there is no link to view a cached version. Is there any way to get a cached version out of chrome, or some alternative method to see the webpage before they changed it?

Comment: If you aren't able to get to the cached version of the site, perhaps you can somehow document that the site is inaccessible and hope for leniency.  Good luck!

Comment: @Mitch, probably not since the assignment was a while ago.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How did you try to use the cached copy from the search engines? Do you mean that you simply searched for the page, then looked the *cached* link next to the result or did you specifically use the *cached* query parameter? For example:

```
https://www.google.com/search?q=cache:myschool.net/homework/blah.html
```

You can also try (with fingers crossed) to see if the page happens to have been cached by the Internet Archive. For example:

```
https://web.archive.org/web/*/myschool.net/homework/blah.html
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try the [Wayback Machine](https://www.archive.org/web/web.php). It will hopefully give you last summer's assignments too. :)

Comment: you sites's link http://wayback.archive.org/web/*/Corebaby.org

Comment: Yup, that’s what I said. Of course it’s less likely to work than the search engine caches because the Internet Archive crawls less frequently, but that’s also why the search engines will be more likely to have a too-up-to-date copy. (Unfortunately, the classic version is no longer available, only the beta version is.)

Comment: agreed . in this case it only has data upto 2009 , no help for sean here ;) +1 for you :)

Comment: I don’t blame them. Unlike the search-engine’s spiders which only cache the most recent copy, the Internet Archive actually downloads and **stores** the copies that it crawls. I can’t/don’t even want to imagine how much space that requires!