# View earlier version of a webpage

Tags: firefox, cache, web

A clothing webshop I bought from sent me an item that didn't match the description from the website. I sent them an email and they told me the information on the website was correct. I went to check and saw that they had adjusted the information to suit my incorrect item (those filthy criminals).

When I bought it, the information was different and I want my money back, but I don't have proof that they changed their webpage. The specific webpage from the item is not available on any cache archive, so is there any way I can view the page from say one, two weeks ago?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any way to access a cached version of a webpage?](http://superuser.com/questions/322611/is-there-any-way-to-access-a-cached-version-of-a-webpage)

Comment: I always print the item detail and order pages, with the header showing the url and the footer showing the date and time.

Answer (score 0):

maybe something is cached [here](http://archive.org/web/), but I also think this wouldn't be proof enough.

In [E-commerce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E-commerce) you are able to step back from a purchase contract 14 days. Here in Austria it is so, maybe where you live too. Check your rights on an online contract. Maybe you don't need a prove and they have the take it back.